# rails: How to populate a model which provides a user with a set of defaults records while allowing them to add more

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, architecture, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to be able to create a feature on a web program to create an Inspection. the inspection has many inspection items. I want to populate inspection_items with an initial number of items but allow the user to add or delete any of the default items. From the architecture standpoint I really do not know how to get this done effectively. I began by having the inspection_item model and create the list from a Hash stored in a constant but that won't allow for the list to e dynamic.

```
class InspectionList < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :workorder


  DEFAULTQUESTIONS = %w[{item_name: "Blablabla"}, 
  {item_name:"Loremipsumboardhordic"}, {item_name: "Satir quajnami grolose"} ]


def initialize(DEFAULTQUESTIONS)
  InspectionList.create(DEFAULTQUESTIONS)
end


end
```

Comment: Just create columns for items you want them to be allowed to update, like :day of week, then create a form and give them permission to crud :day of week?? If you want :day of week to default to Monday you can etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you first need to add a table plus model for the Inspection items:

```
class InspectionItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inspection_list
end

class InspectionList < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inspection_items
end
```

Then, when presenting a new inspection list to the user (e.g. in the `new` controller action in `inspection_lists_controller`), you can build up the first few default inspection items and attach them to the new inspection list:

```
@inspection_list = InspectionList.new
@inspection_list.add_default_items
```

where `add_default_items` does the building of the attached items itself (and I'd probably put this in the `InspectionList` model), and yes, a constant is a suitable place for it:

```
# app/models/inspection_list.rb
DEFAULT_ITEMS = [{item_name: "Blablabla"}, 
                 {item_name:"Loremipsumboardhordic"}, 
                 {item_name: "Satir quajnami grolose"} ]

def add_default_items
  DEFAULT_ITEMS.each do |item|
    self.inspection_items.build(item)
  end 
end
```

The `build` method is [documented e.g. here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many-collection-build-attributes) and attaches the newly built association record (inspection item) to the main record (inspection list).

Comment: your solution makes sense however I am getting the following message:When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument. and the issue is on this line:self.inspection_items.build(item) Any idea why?

Comment: Aha, sorry, you need to remove the `%w` from your `DEFAULT_ITEMS` definition, I mistakingly left it there while copy pasting. Then it should work. The `%w` is used to define an array from space-separated symbols which is not the case of the array of hashes used there.